How can I make a list item default selected in Floating UI (React)?
I was following the guide for creating a composite select menu using Floating UI (React). The code sandbox provided by them is here.
This perfectly works, basis there is no previous value which is auto filled. I want to use this as a form select menu, which can take a default value, a value for the option and the ability to disable some option based on value.
Is there a possibility to reuse this composite structure and achieve the functionality?
Example expectation:
<Select onChange={handler} value={2}>
    <Option label={"Option 1"} value={1}>
    <Option label={"Option 1"} value={2}>
    <Option label={"Option 1"} value={3}>
</Select>

Any help, guides, discussions are very much appreciated.
